# How to check if a string is in a list of strings

Tags: csv, powershell, output

I am trying to get my script to output an error when someone enters an incorrect hostname from a CSV file.

Here is the script I have

```
#get content from file
$data= import-csv ".\Earliest Date Template.csv"

#which Hostname do you want to look up
$hostid=Read-Host "Please enter Hostname"

#Error Conditions
$spellingerror=$hostid -notmatch "Hostname"

if ($spellingerror) 
  {Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "Hostname does not exist"}
else
  {$data | Sort-Object {[DateTime]$_."Last Modified"} |   
  Where-Object   {$_."Hostname" -eq $hostid} |  Select -First 1 -       
  ExpandProperty "Last Modified"
  }
Break
```

The script is designed to ask the user for which host they want to know about and when it was first modified and if the hostname does not exist spit out it does not exist.
No matter what I do it keeps spitting out Hostname does not exist.

Here is a sample from the contents of my CSV file.

```
Hostname    Last Modified
HD          9/8/2012
LOG         9/15/2004
NETMAN     12/25/2004
NETMAN      5/5/2015
LOG        2/14/2013
LOG        6/6/2011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this error condition:

```
$spellingerror = $hostid -notin $data.hostname
```

Comment: Pre PS 3.0: `($data | % { $_.Hostname}) -notcontains $hostid`